# How to update DE records (>10 years AND <1990)equal to NULL in SFMC Using SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sql, automationstudio, birthday

How to null birthday records below 10 years and birthday records of those born before 1990 using SQL in Salesforce marketing cloud.
Here in my DE Birthday is text field.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT [ID],
NULL AS [Birthday]
FROM [TableName]
WHERE CAST([Birthday] AS DATE) < '1990-01-01'
OR CAST([Birthday] AS DATE) > CAST(DATEADD(year, -10, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
```